# Remove HTML extension for specific URL without Redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to remove or hide the .html for a single URL without doing a 301 redirect? All of the examples I have come across involve rewriting all the URLs and some sort of redirect.

I would like to rewrite the following URL:

http://www.somesite.com/literature.html

to

http://www.somesite.com/literature

All of the other URLs should be unaffected and render the .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this simple rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(literature)/?$ /$.html [NC,L]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

This will internally load `http://www.somesite.com/literature.html` when you open `http://www.somesite.com/literature` in your browser.

Answer (score 4):

You could just make a directory like this

```
/literature/index.html
```

and move the literature.html to index.html in that sub directory and the url /literature should use the default page index.html

You can do it with PHP or another server-side language, but that didn't seem like what you were asking.

Comment: gotta admit, that is so simple that it seems too easy to work, but it's fairly brilliant if you ask me

Comment: While this does work brilliantly in my local, serving it to Github Pages kinda breaks the relative URLs for pages served inside a `folder` with `index.html`